# How to address media queries not working in Refinery CMS for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari, refinerycms

I created my rails app to be responsive. It has the most noticeable difference in the footer, where the menu becomes more friendly for people with larger fingers.

When testing my app in Firefox and I reduced the width, the mobile styles are visible, as below:
[image: in firefox]

But when I tested in the iOS simulator, I got this result

[image: in iOS Simulator]

My first instinct was to check in the head for the viewport meta tag.

In RefineryCMS, this seems to be the default:

```
<meta charset='<%= Rails.application.config.encoding %>' />
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" /><![endif]-->
<title><%= browser_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
<%= raw %(<meta name="description" content="#{@meta.meta_description}" />) if @meta.meta_description.present? -%>
<%= raw %(<link rel="canonical" content="#{@canonical}" />) if @canonical.present? -%>
<%= csrf_meta_tags if Refinery::Core.authenticity_token_on_frontend -%>
<%= yield :meta %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<%= yield :stylesheets %>
<%= render '/refinery/google_analytics' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'modernizr-min' %>
```

So not being there, I then added it before the title to test

```
<meta charset='<%= Rails.application.config.encoding %>' />
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" /><![endif]-->
<meta name="viewport" id="view" content="width=device-width minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<title><%= browser_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
```

This is the result that I got

[image: new footer]

But is there anything else that I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

According to [This blog post](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/viewport-meta-tag-for-non-responsive-design)

> the default viewport width on iPhone is 980px

and a viewport is encouraged regardless of the project being responsive or not. But you are warned against not allowing user scalable

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

The problem in this case was solved by adding the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

As discussed. And yes the problem is mostly limited to the iPhone (among various mobile devices) because of its default viewport size.